# Open Jpa OneToMany parent relationship with two level down child

Tags: java, spring-boot, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin

How can I make a relationship with a second-level child using openjpa.

```
Parent -> Child -> GrandChild
```

Parent has a property lets say, plant, the child does not have it, however the grand child do. So, how can I make a relationship to the grand child directly from parent in order to get only those children having same plant as their parent in their child level(GrandChild). (Preferably one sided).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to move from Parent --> Plant --> GrandChilds.

Meaning you will need:

- A ManyToOne in the Parent with Plant
- A OneToMany in the Plant with List< GrandChild >

---

Additionally (to be coherent)

- A OneToMany in the Plant with List< Parent >
- A ManyToOne in the GrandChild with Plan

After doing so you will be able to do:

```
parent.getPlant().getGrandChilds()
```